# Does any DNS Recursive resolver accept a "DNSSEC-only" option under DNSCurve?

Tags: encryption, privacy, dns, integrity, dnssec

I want to use DNSCurve (for privacy) to a trusted DNSSec resolver (for integrity), and want to ensure that I can tell a recursive resolver (like 8.8.8.8, or OpenDNS) that I *only* want DNSSec queries.

Logically this would be similar to issuing either of the following options:

- Recurse
- No Recurse

**Question**

Does such a technique exist, no matter if it is enforced by a DNS recursive resolver (mentioned above) or as a proposed RFC enhancement to the passive DNS client to Server protocol?

Comment: Is DNSCurve a requirement for an acceptable solution for you?

Comment: @schroeder I'm writing an app for iOS and Android that requests resolution of a DNS name. I assume that no such extension exists, or for idealistic reasons, it doesn't exist either.  I want to have a guarantee to my app that the DNS host is really the DNS host that is expected ... (using a local resolver, or an imported Java or iOS resolver)

Answer (score 2):

It appears that secure DNSSec recursive queries are not possible to enforce.

According to the notes in this [IETF draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-livingood-negative-trust-anchors-07):

> DNSSEC is not an enforcement mechanism, it's a resource. When I see
> folks voice opinions that DNSSEC's recommended operation has to
> strictly followed, my gut reaction is that these folks have forgotten
> the purpose of all of our efforts. ~ [Ed Lewis](https://www.neustar.biz/blog/authors/edward-lewis)

DNSSEC is offered as a help and DNS servers can be configured to maintain the security of the recursion chain, or not. It also appears form Mr Lewis' comment, that there might not be a method to enforce secure recursion for some time.

Comment: I just read that note...  somewhat abstract points he is saying.  He does seem to say that a "local policy" is what trumps a global policy... specifically on the Caching Server.  If a caching server is in my "local policy" realm of influence, I don't see why I can't have a local policy that says "ensure that this DNS label is not spoofed via DNSSEC".  Since he works for Ultra, and I'm a UltraDNS customer, I'll open a support ticket....